# What is the best way to form this layout using iText7?

Tags: java, layout, itext7

I am trying to create this layout in PDF
The page layout is single table on the top with 100% width (marked with red color - table 1)
And side by side tables (each brown box is a table table 2 to table 7)

brown tables have constant sizes and constant positions
I was able to successfully create the title and table1 using:

```
 table.useAllAvailableWidth();
```

My problem is with the rest of the tables (marked in the image as brown)
I tried to lay them side by side using:

```
    table2.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
    table2.setMaxWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(50f));

    table3.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
    table3.setMaxWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(50f));
```

But they wont align together on the same line but one below the other

My question is what is the correct way to achieve this pdf layout?

[image: desired pdf layout]

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that those brown tables have constant sizes and positions? Or can their sizes change making the layout not strictly like the sketch?

Comment: For layouts like this, I'd use HTML and then use iText 7's pdfHTML add-on to convert the HTML to PDF.

Comment: @mkl  yes brown tables have constant sizes and constant positions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the *tables have constant sizes and constant positions*, you can simply use the iText 7 feature of setting fixed positions, widths, and heights in particular for tables:

```cs
/**
 * Sets values for a absolute repositioning of the Element.
 * The coordinates specified correspond to the
 * bottom-left corner of the element and it grows upwards.
 * Also has as a side effect that the Element's {@link Property#POSITION} is changed to
 * {@link LayoutPosition#FIXED fixed}.
 *
 * @param left   horizontal position of the bottom-left corner on the page
 * @param bottom vertical position of the bottom-left corner on the page
 * @param width  a floating point value measured in points.
 * @return this Element.
 */
public T setFixedPosition(float left, float bottom, float width)

/**
 * Sets the height property a block element as a point-value.
 *
 * @param height a floating point value for the new height
 * @return the block element itself.
 */
public T setHeight(float height)
```

You get approximately your sketched layout like this:

```cs
try (   PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(...));
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument)) {
    PageSize pageSize = pdfDocument.getDefaultPageSize();

    Table table = new Table(1);
    table.addCell("table 1 - 1");
    table.addCell("table 1 - 2");
    table.setFixedPosition(pageSize.getLeft() + 30, pageSize.getTop() - 75, pageSize.getWidth() - 60);
    table.setHeight(45);
    document.add(table);

    table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[] {40, 60}));
    table.addCell("table 2 - 1");
    table.addCell("table 2 - 2");
    table.setFixedPosition(pageSize.getLeft() + 30, pageSize.getTop() - 265, (pageSize.getWidth() - 70) / 2);
    table.setHeight(185);
    document.add(table);

    table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[] {20, 50, 30}));
    table.addCell("table 4 - 1");
    table.addCell("table 4 - 2");
    table.addCell("table 4 - 3");
    table.setFixedPosition(pageSize.getLeft() + 30, pageSize.getTop() - 720, (pageSize.getWidth() - 70) / 2);
    table.setHeight(450);
    document.add(table);

    table = new Table(1);
    table.addCell("table 6");
    table.setFixedPosition(pageSize.getLeft() + 30, pageSize.getTop() - 810, (pageSize.getWidth() - 70) / 2);
    table.setHeight(85);
    document.add(table);

    table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[] {20, 40, 20, 20}));
    table.addCell("table 3 - 1");
    table.addCell("table 3 - 2");
    table.addCell("table 3 - 3");
    table.addCell("table 3 - 4");
    table.setFixedPosition(pageSize.getRight() - (pageSize.getWidth() - 10) / 2, pageSize.getTop() - 345, (pageSize.getWidth() - 70) / 2);
    table.setHeight(265);
    document.add(table);

    table = new Table(1);
    table.addCell("table 5 - 1");
    table.addCell("table 5 - 2");
    table.setFixedPosition(pageSize.getRight() - (pageSize.getWidth() - 10) / 2, pageSize.getTop() - 640, (pageSize.getWidth() - 70) / 2);
    table.setHeight(290);
    document.add(table);

    table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[] {20, 50, 30}));
    table.addCell("table 7 - 1");
    table.addCell("table 7 - 2");
    table.addCell("table 7 - 3");
    table.setFixedPosition(pageSize.getRight() - (pageSize.getWidth() - 10) / 2, pageSize.getTop() - 810, (pageSize.getWidth() - 70) / 2);
    table.setHeight(165);
    document.add(table);
}
```

*([FixedPositionLayouts](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/FixedPositionLayouts.java#L37) test `testFixedTablePositions`)*

The result:

[image: screen shot]

*(As you did not give exact coordinates, the above can only be an approximation. You'll have to adapt the values accordingly.)*